# $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is not uniformly continuous in $|z|<1$, $z \ne 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Show that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is not uniformly continuous in $|z|<1$, $z \ne 0$. Suppose by the sake of contradiction that it is, then for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $z_1,z_2$ such that $|z_1|<1$ and $|z_2|<1$,  $|z_1-z_2|<\delta(\epsilon) \implies \left|\frac{1}{z_1}-\frac{1}{z_2}\right|<\epsilon$.

Suppose without loss of generality that it is $0<\delta(\epsilon)<1$, then since the definition of uniform continuity holds for all $z_1,z_2$ such that $|z_1|<1$ and $|z_2|<1$ I can choose $z_1=\delta(\epsilon)$ and (since $\frac{\delta(\epsilon)}{1+\epsilon} <\delta(\epsilon)<1$) I can choose $z_2=\frac{\delta(\epsilon)}{1+\epsilon}$ for it follows
$$\left|\frac{1}{\delta(\epsilon)}-\frac{1}{\frac{\delta(\epsilon)}{1+\epsilon}}\right|<\epsilon$$
But $\left|\frac{1}{\delta(\epsilon)}-\frac{1}{\frac{\delta(\epsilon)}{1+\epsilon}}\right|=\frac{\epsilon}{\delta(\epsilon)}$, so it is $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta(\epsilon)}<\epsilon \iff \delta(\epsilon)>1$ but this contradicts the fact that $\delta(\epsilon)<1$. So $f$ is not uniformly continuous in $|z|<1$. Is this correct? I am not sure because I'm not sure if all my supposition are correct, in particular: I'm not sure that I can suppose $\delta(\epsilon)<1$, because this is a proof by contradiction so I suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous and I don't know if the $\delta(\epsilon)$ I get is actually $<1$ (but I think this is ok because if $\delta(\epsilon) \geq 1$ is the one that works for the uniform continuity then all the $\delta^*(\epsilon)<1$ work as well) and I'm not sure if the fact that when I get $\delta(\epsilon)>1$ I actually get a contradiction, since it was a supposition of mine that $\delta(\epsilon)<1$.

Comment: $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is not even _defined_ in $|z|<1$. Please be more precise!

Comment: @TonyK: You are right, thank you. I have added that $z \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not uniformly continuous as it doesn't send Cauchy sequences in the domain to Cauchy sequences, which is an easily verifiable property of uniformly continuous functions. Consider the Cauchy sequence $z_n = \frac{1}{n}$ in the domain, e.g.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are you considering $z_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 2$? Because if $n=1$ then $\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|=1$ and so the condition $|z|<1$ is not satisfied. Does this influence something or it is ok because $\frac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence for $n \geq 2$ as well?
Can you answer to my doubts too, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Gwyn yes for $n \ge 2$ is fine. A subsequence of a Cauchy sequence is still Cauchy.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sir, none of the answers here, gives what OP asked? He asked for solution verification. Sir I have same question! I also wants to know, how we can suppose $0< \delta < 1$ ? Definition of uniform continuity does not say anything about this! It just say " For give $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that, for any two points $z, z_0$ in the region, se have $|f(z) -f(z_0) |<\epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0|<\delta$. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon =1$, let $1>\delta >0$.

If $x= \delta /2$ and $y=\delta$ then $|x-y|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|=1/\delta>\epsilon.$

Therefore $f$ is, by definition, not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$ then $f$ is bounded in $(a,b)$. Since your function is not bounded couldn't be uniformly continuous.

Check this: [If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$, then $f$ is bounded on $(a, b)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024943/if-f-is-uniformly-continuous-on-a-b-then-f-is-bounded-on-a-b)